# Am I reading May's Van Kampen's theorem correctly?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

May's concise algebraic topology states the van Kampen theorem as follows.

> [image]

I'm unsure whether I'm reading it correctly, since the I get to absurd results: Suppose $X$ is some subspace of a larger space, and suppose  $\mathcal O$ is some cover of $X$, such that the result holds. Now suppose I construct another open cover $\mathcal O'$ from $\mathcal O$ by adding another space $Y$ to it, that intersects with neither $X$ nor with any of the elements of $\mathcal O$. Then $\mathcal O'$ is again an open cover of $X$, but the colimit of its fundamental groupoids can't be isomorphic to the one of $\mathcal O$, since we added a set to it that is not path connected to any of the ones in $\mathcal O$.

Where is my reasoning wrong, or where am I misreading the statement?

Comment: Why are you regarding $X$ as a subspace of another space? $X$ is a space in itself with its own cover that are each subsets of $X$. If you want to think of $X$ as being a subspace of some space $Z$ and each of the elements of the cover being open sets in $Z$, then you're working out $\Pi \left(\cup U'\right)$, not $\Pi X$. If you want your setup to tell you something about $X$, you should be considering the open sets as being the induced open sets in $X$, i.e. $U \cap X$, for which any of the new open sets that you add are empty.

Comment: Ok, I couldn't make out from the statement that the $U$'s are subsets of $X$.